# PowerShell move computer to OU

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script that moves computer to an OU in Active Directory.

My computer have Active Directory installed, so when I run the script, it moves my computer to an OU of my choice.

I tested the script on a different computer that does not have Active Directory installed, and it failed to move.

[image]

Any idea how I could get the script to work in a computer that does not have AD installed?

Comment: What you need is the ActiveDirectory PowerShell module.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kind of new to PowerShell, how would I add that?

Comment: It's part of RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools). Download, install and then activate that windows feature.

Comment: If the module is already installed you can load with the command `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`. On more recent PowerShell version it's even loaded automatically when you use one of its cmdlets. For installing the module see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34596272/1630171).

Comment: Thank you all, I'll try that

Comment: Thanks to everyone, once I downloaded RSAT and added the features, I was able to run my script.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without installing AD module on all workstations?  Is there a way to run it from a server?

Comment: [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) is one way to run commands on a remote host.